# Search using Select Dropdown in PHP (Oracle database)?

Tags: php, oracle

I'm making a website with a search function using select dropdown and am having a hard time. I want the web to be able to search for both model and group name at the same time or maybe just search for model/groupname.

I tried some ways but it didn't work.Because I'm new to programming, my knowledge is still poor, so I hope everyone can help me with my mistake or can keep me a code with similar content for reference. Thank you very much.

Code is:

```
<?php
include '../includes/dbconnection.php';

$sql = "SELECT * 
FROM SFISM4.R_STATION_ATE_T
WHERE WORK_DATE= TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYYMMDD') "; 
    try{
      $params = [];
      if(isset($_GET['model'], $_GET['group']) && $_GET['model'] && $_GET['group']){
        $sql = $sql. 'AND MODEL_NAME=:MODEL_NAME '.'AND GROUP_NAME=:GROUP_NAME';
        $params= [
          'MODEL_NAME' => $_GET['model'],
          'GROUP_NAME' => $_GET['group']
        ];
      }
      $stm = $db->prepare($sql);
      $stm->execute($params);
      $result = $stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
 
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }

    try{
      $stm = $db->prepare('SELECT DISTINCT MODEL_NAME FROM SFISM4.R_STATION_ATE_T ');
      $stm->execute();
      $result_model = $stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    }catch(PDOException $e){
      echo $e->getMessage();
    }

    try{
        $stm = $db->prepare('SELECT DISTINCT GROUP_NAME FROM SFISM4.R_STATION_ATE_T');
        $stm->execute();
        $result_group = $stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Station Detail</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  </head>
  <body >
    <div class="container" >
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">

          <div class="well" style="background-color:LightGray;">
             <h2 class="text-center">Station Details</h2>
          </div>

          <form method="get">

            <select  name="model" id="model" style="">
                <option value="">- MODEL_NAME -</option>
                <?php foreach($result_model as $key => $value):?>
                  <option value="<?=$value->MODEL_NAME?>" <?= (isset($_GET['model']) && $_GET['model'] == $value->MODEL_NAME) ? 'selected' : '' ?>><?=$value->MODEL_NAME?></option>
                <?php endforeach; ?>

            </select>

            <select name="group" id="group">
                <option value="">- GROUP_NAME -</option>
                <?php foreach($result_group as $key => $value):?>
                    <option value="<?=$value->GROUP_NAME?>" <?= (isset($_GET['group']) && $_GET['group'] == $value->GROUP_NAME) ? 'selected' : '' ?>><?=$value->GROUP_NAME?></option>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </select>

            <button class="btn btn-success btn-primary" type="submit" name="filter" id="filter" style="">
                <i class="fa fa-filter"></i> Filter
            </button>

          </form>          
          
          <br/><br/>

          <table class="table table-hover table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>MODEL_NAME</th>
                <th>GROUP_NAME</th>
                <th>STATION_NAME</th>
                <th>WORK_DATE</th>
                <th>PASS_QTY</th>
                <th>FAIL_QTY</th>
               
              </tr>
              <?php
                foreach($result as $key => $value):
              ?>
              <tr>
                <td> <?php echo $value['MODEL_NAME']?></td>
                <td> <?php echo $value['GROUP_NAME']; ?>
                <td> <?=$value['STATION_NAME']; ?>
                <td> <?=$value['WORK_DATE']; ?>
                <td> <?=$value['PASS_QTY']; ?>
                <td> <?=$value['FAIL_QTY'] ?>
                    
              </tr>
              <?php endforeach; ?>
            </thead>
          </table>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may amend the code so that the `$sql` and `$params` will depend on whether there is/are actually $_GET['model'] and/or $_GET['group']

So change the block

```
$params = [];
      if(isset($_GET['model'], $_GET['group']) && $_GET['model'] && $_GET['group']){
        $sql = $sql. 'AND MODEL_NAME=:MODEL_NAME '.'AND GROUP_NAME=:GROUP_NAME';
        $params= [
          'MODEL_NAME' => $_GET['model'],
          'GROUP_NAME' => $_GET['group']
        ];
      }
```

to

```
$model="";
$group="";

if(isset($_GET['model'])){
  $model=$_GET["model"];
}

if(isset($_GET['group'])){
  $group=$_GET["group"];
}

  $params = [];

   if(isset($model) && $model!=""){   
     $sql = $sql. ' AND MODEL_NAME=:MODEL_NAME ' ;
     $params['MODEL_NAME']=$model;
    }

   if(isset($group) && $group!=""){   
     $sql = $sql. ' AND GROUP_NAME=:GROUP_NAME ' ;
     $params['GROUP_NAME']=$group;
    }
```

By using the code above,

- if there is no $group nor $model, then the $sql will not contain these 2 conditions.
- If only one of them exists, then only the corresponding condition will be added by "AND".
- If both $group and $model exist, then both will be added to the condition.

Answer (score 0):

I don't speak PHP, but I presume that's irrelevant for what you asked:

> I want the web to be able to search independently for 1 select or both at the same time.

If I understood you correctly, these "both searches" are to be done for model/or group name. If that's so, then modify query to look like this:

```
select * 
from sfism4.r_station_ate_t
where work_date= to_char(sysdate, 'YYYYMMDD')
  and (model_name = :model_name or :model_name is null)
  and (group_name = :group_name or :group_name is null)
```

Comment: Thank you and sorry for the unclear wording of the question. I mean : It is possible to search both model and group name at the same time or just search for model or group .

Comment: This query lets you search by none of them (so you'll get ALL rows), one of them (so rows will be filtered by model OR group name), or both of them (so rows will be filtered by model AND group name).